# Using "right()" and "strpos()" to get rightpart of string for QGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

The strpos() function searches from the left side of the string. But instead of always trimming the string, I would like to get the position from the right side. Is there anyway to do this in the field calculator?

Here is the specific case of application:

[image]

I wanted to get the part of the string in "FolderPath" up the first '/' from the right.

Comment: I think this is a pure Python question about string manipulation that you would be better researching at [so].

Comment: Maybe,but I needed to solve it immediately and am not as firm to python as I wanted to be. Without creating a auxiliary field I used: right("FolderPath",length("FolderPath")-29). Since there are always 29 characters infront of my aimed string part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `regexp_substr` instead of `strpos` so in your example something like:

```
regexp_substr("FolderPath",'.*/')
```

The first item (`"FolderPath"`) is your column name (enclosed in `"`), the second is a [standard python regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). There is a [regexp howto](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) available to help you out.

Comment: I'm playing around with your suggestion, but it doesnt work. ofc i used"regexp_substr()". Do you have a good documentation what to write in the 'regex'?